# C# user input for loop not working correctly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, loops, for-loop

i'm creating a program in C# to print numbers from user entered numbers, userInput1 = 1 and UserInput2 = 10 then print numbers 1 to 10 but also if userInput1 < userInput2 then print a decreasing value, userInput1 = 50 and userInput2 = 20 then print 50 to 20. this is my code but for some reason it's not working.

```
Console.Write("Write a starting vlue: ");
int t1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Write an ending value: ");
int t2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

int i = t1;
if (t1 < t2)
{
    for (i = t1; i <= t2; i--)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i--);
    }
}

        for (i = t1; i <= t2; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

when i write first number as 20 and second number as 1 i get no output instead of 20,19,18,17,16... if anyone knows a solution to this problem please share.

Comment: 1st number is 20: t1 = 20 and your 2nd number is 1: t2 = 1;  You are checking for if (t1 < t2) {...}, obviously, it is going to skip the whole loop. Write a condition for: if (t1 < t2) {....}  else {...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `for` loops like this and use an `else` statement:

```
if (t1 < t2)
{
    for (i = t1; i <= t2; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
else 
{
     for (i = t1; i >= t2; i--)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

In the first loop you should increment `i` because `t1` is less than `t2`.And do not change the value of `i` inside the body of your loop because you already changing it on each iteration.If you change it again then you will *skip* one step on each iteration.